# How do I make a left shift (offset) without using the plot function?

Tags: pine-script

I need to shift the values to the left by x, but using plot() I can't use this variable later in calculations, also in pine script there is an offset () function, but it only shifts the values to the right, and I need to the left. Such a problem has led me to a dead end.

[image]